# log4net security context can't find domain

Tags: log4net-configuration

I have a config file to log to a SQL server database. 
The logging works fine when I use a sql account, but I need to use a windows account to access the database. Thus I changed the config file to include SecurityContext.

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
<bufferSize value="1" />
<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
<connectionString value="data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DB;integrated security=false;persist security info=True" />
<securityContext type="log4net.Util.WindowsSecurityContext">
  <domain value ="DOMAIN"/>
  <userName value="USER" />
  <password value="PASSWORD" />      
</securityContext>
```

But this does not work. I turned on the internal logging and to my surprise I get

```
log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Cannot find Property [domain] to set object on [log4net.Util.WindowsSecurityContext]
```

But I have defined domain in the securityContext. Why does it not recognize my domain?

Answer (score 0):

After encountering the same problem, I found it's most likely the solution is in renaming the property `domain` to `domainName`. For future reference:

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DB;integrated security=false;persist security info=True" />
    <securityContext type="log4net.Util.WindowsSecurityContext">
        <domainName value="DOMAIN" />
        <userName value="USER" />
        <password value="PASSWORD" />      
    </securityContext>
</appender>
```